# Why does setState empty the state object, instead of removing it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, undefined

In a logout method I'm trying to set a state value to null.

```
this.setState({
  activeUser: null
});
```

Then, in my render, I'm checking `if(!this.state.activeUser)`. However, on the first call to `setState`, it's merely emptying out the `activeUser` object. `activeUser: {}`. I can repeat the call:

```
this.setState({
  activeUser: null
});
```

Which then removes the `activeUser` property, but this feels like a hack-around. I'm not sure if I'm running into a language issue or react issue. I'd rather not change the render check, but maybe that's the answer.

```
// No, thank you.
if (!this.state.activeUser || typeof(this.state.activeUser) === 'undefined')
```

Comment: Does this only happen when setting to `null`? Logically speaking I'd use a boolean here. I'm trying to find docs, but I'm starting to think null values are removed from the state?

Comment: "Which then removes the `activeUser` property" --- I hardly doubt it's what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which then removes the `activeUser` property

No, it is not removing the property, just setting its value to `null`. To remove the property itself, you should use `delete`:

```
delete this.state.activeUser;
```

However, this is bad because it changes the state. Consider using a library like immutability helpers.

Comment: `delete this.setState.activeUser;` --- are you confident this would work?

Comment: @zerkms The damned copy/paste, somebody has to create a popup warning for it, just like the warning when you write in an email *see attached*, then try to send it without the attachment :). Thanks for the note.

Comment: haha :-) Btw, `removeByKey` is nearly to useless in this case: `setState` does not overwrite but merges the state. So even if you create an object without some key - you wouldn't be able to remove it through the `setState()`

Comment: So you pass there a state, get the state object back (without some key). What's next? I think reassigning `this.state` is not allowed.

Comment: @zerkms *not allowed* is a big word, sure you can, but you're right it isn't any better than using `delete` which I already said it's bad. I removed it from the answer.

Comment: "sure you can" --- but then the behaviour is not determined. It may pick the new object, it may ignore it, or something else might happen.

Comment: Yes, that's why I called it "bad" :)

Comment: Sounds like my best option is to check for empty object. I get what you're saying @RacilHilan, but then when I set the empty object to null, it is deleted by `setState`

Comment: Yes, checking for empty object is probably the best option.